# In SQL how do I update a table with a similar table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In my current Database I have a table whose data is manually entered or comes in an excel sheet every week. Before we had the "manual entry option", the table would be dropped and replaced by the excel version. 
Now because there is data that only exists in the original table this can not be done.
I'm trying to find a way to update the original table with changes and additions from the (excel) table while preserving all rows not in the new sheet.

I've been attempting to simply use an insert query and an update query /but/ I can't find a way to detect changes in a record.

Any suggestions? I can provide the current sql if you'd find that helpful.

Comment: What does the table structure look like? What rules do you need for the insert/update query?

Comment: Is there a field or combination of fields which uniquely identifies each row ... both in the table and sheet?

Comment: @hansUp There is an ID that serves as a unique Identifier except there are many with null values..

Comment: Many Null `ID` where ... in the table; the sheet; both?  What should happen with a row which has Null `ID`?  Is it a new record?  An update of an existing record?  How can you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I have read so far, I think I can offer some suggestions:

It appears you have control of the MS Access.  I would suggest adding a field to your data table called "source".  Modify your form in the access database to store something like "m" for manual entry in the source field.  When you import the excel, store an "e" for excel in the field.

You would need to do a one time scrub of the data to mark existing records as manual entries or excel entries.  There are a couple of ways you can do it through automation/queries that I can explain in detail if you want.

Once past these steps, your excel process is fairly simple.  You can delete all records with source = "e" and then do a full excel import.  Manual records would remain unchanged.

This concept will allow you to add new sources and codes and allow you to handle each differently if needed.  You just need to spend some time cleaning up your old data.  I think you will find it worth it in the end.

Good Luck.